# Problems with Plupload

Tags: jquery, silverlight, flash, html, plupload

I am using plupload (v 1.4.3.2) and set it up a few weeks ago and everything worked. I have not touched it since then.

Now it does not work. The file gets to 100% then I get this great descriptive error

IO error. Error #2038

```
 var renderImportForm = $(selectors.uploader).livequery(function ()
    {

        var uploader = $(this).plupload({
            // General settings
            runtimes: 'html5,silverlight,flash',
            url: urls.importCalendarsURL,
            max_file_size: '5mb',
            max_file_count: 10, // user can add no more then 10 files at a time
            unique_names: true,
            multiple_queues: true,
            // Resize images on clientside if we can
            resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },

            // Rename files by clicking on their titles
            rename: true,

            // Sort files
            sortable: true,

            // Specify what files to browse for
            filters: [
                { title: "iCalendar", extensions: "ics" }
            ],


            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url: my.uploaderSettings.flash,

            // Silverlight settings
            silverlight_xap_url: my.uploaderSettings.silverLight,

            init:
            {
                UploadComplete: function (up, file, info)
                {
                   alert('hi');
                }
            }
        });
```

The above code works.

If I flip it around to what it was originally(what was set a few weeks ago)

```
        runtimes: 'flash,html5,silverlight,'
```

it does not work. So this leads me to believe it is a problem with flash as html 5 works.

silverlight does not work as well different problem though. It won't launch a dialog box when you click "add files".

No javascript errors come up in firebug.

Comment: @chrxian -http://www.plupload.com/index.php

Answer (score 5):

use chunks or/and urlstream_upload:true

edit: That error is flash error. above settings should do the trick. There's some problems with flash without those settings. I don't remember accurately what it was. Admin from plupload's forums:

> You do not use chunks, and do not force Plupload into urlstream mode... it might be sessions problem on your server. Have you maybe activated sessions on your server recently?
>   If it's sessions problem the easiest way to solve it in your case, would be to set: urlstream_upload option to true.

http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=4308#p4308

Answer (score 1):

Add the following config:

```
headers: {
    Authorization: ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the folder/directory to which the files are uploaded exists or not
That would help you

Comment: I store it in memory and extract what I need and put it into the database.